# Opencv - python - Join line segments from Line Segment Detector (LSD) to form one line

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, straight-line-detection

I am working on this problem of finding popping crease of the cricket pitch and I have somewhat achieved what I wanted to do that is I can detect vertical line segments using LSD from opencv but what I dont seem to understand is how to join different line segments on the same line to make a complete line.

The code for finding line segments:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

#Read gray image
img = cv2.imread("2.jpg",0)

#Create default parametrization LSD
lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)

#Detect lines in the image
lines = lsd.detect(img)[0] #Position 0 of the returned tuple are the detected lines
print(lines[0][0][0])

ver_lines = []

for line in lines:
    angletan = math.degrees(math.atan2((round(line[0][3],2) - round(line[0][1],2)), (round(line[0][2],2) - round(line[0][0],2))))

    if(angletan > 85 and angletan < 95):
        ver_lines.append(line)

#Draw detected lines in the image
drawn_img = lsd.drawSegments(img,np.array(ver_lines))

#Show image
cv2.imshow("LSD",drawn_img )
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Input Image:[image]

Detected lines:[image]

what I would like to have:[image]

Comment: First segment the image to get only the white line, using color segmentation, then use LSD on the binary output.